# how to copy a deeply nested binary file from one git repo to another

Tags: files, git

I want to copy an image file from one github repo to another. The source and destination file paths are deeply nested within the repo (eg. copy `~/code/repo1/src/components/A/components/B/common/components/C/images/image1.png` to `~/code/repo2/src/components/D/images/image1.png`, so I want a convenient way to construct the file paths without manually typing them.

Ideally the solution would involve fuzzy file finding so that it's easy to construct the path to `image1.png` without having to type the directory names.

Comment: The question does not seem to be about Emacs.

Comment: What if I appended " in emacs" to the title? The idea is this comes up when I'm editing code and I'd like to accomplish it without leaving emacs

Comment: Consider asking it on StackOverflow or another StackExchange site. It's a shell question, regardless of where you execute the shell command. You can use shell within Emacs, of course, and if/when you get the shell answer you can apply it to your use of shell in Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

This solution constructs a `cp` command in a `shell` using [`helm-ls-git`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-ls-git) to fuzzy-find the source and destination.

- `M-x customize-variable helm-ls-git-fuzzy-match` set to `on`
- `M-x shell` to open a shell in a new window
- open any file in `repo1`, then `M-x helm-ls-git-ls` and fuzzy-find `image1.png`
- `C-u C-c C-k` (`helm-kill-selection-and-quit)` to copy the file path from helm
- switch to the `shell` window, type `cp` and `C-y` to yank the `image1.png` source file path
- open any file in `repo2`, then `M-x helm-ls-git-ls` and fuzzy-find a file within the destination directory (or something close to it)
- `C-u C-c C-k` (`helm-kill-selection-and-quit)` to copy the destination path from helm
- switch back to the `shell` buffer and `C-y` to paste. Modify the destination appropriately (eg. removing filename) if the previous step returned an inexact destination.

This will result in a `cp` command that you can execute to copy the file. Afterwards, kill the `shell` and its buffer.

You may bind `helm-ls-git-ls` to a convenient shortcut if desired (for example, `(global-set-key [?\C-c ?f] (quote helm-ls-git-ls))`).

Comment: All of this to avoid typing two pathnames? And why do it in shell and not open the two directories in emacs and use `dired-dwim-target`?

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution, I did not know about `dired-dwim-target`. Also explained here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5604